# How to make a password that unlocks with buttons clicked in a specific order

Tags: javascript, button, passwords

I've recently created a few piano keys using HTML, CSS and some Javascript and I would like to know how to go about creating a password that only unlocks when certain keys are played in a specific order.

I imagine the code would go something like:

if (correct sequence of keys are input) {

unlocks secret content;

}else{

message: try again!;

}

I've never made a password lock of any kind and I'm not sure what language would be idea for a password... Ideally it would word in browsers and on phones. I'm really new to javascript and I know that people can easily see your code so I guess I can't really use that because people would look for the password. Any ideas/guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: with client-side-only, you can let each key mean a letter that when all stacked up, points to a secret and hard-to-guess url.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want users to see the login credentials, you'll need to include some server side code with PHP, or ASP.NET for example so that the check is done on the server and not in the users browser.

But otherwise it would be fairly simple to do this piano key check by making each click on the buttons add a new character to a string.

```
var pw="";
document.getElementById('key1').onclick=function(){pw +="x"};
```

And then just do a standard check on that string to a saved password.